# View nested private function definitions in PowerShell

Tags: function, reflection, powershell, module

PowerShell provides a simple technique to view the contents of a function, e.g.

```
Get-Content function:MyFuncName   # (A)
```

or equivalently

```
(Get-ChildItem function:MyFuncName).definition    # (B)
```

where *MyFuncName* is the name of my function. That is great for *simple* functions (i.e. functions that use only base language constructs and do not call other functions). But consider the function `foo` shown below that contains a call to the function `bar`. In a typical scenario these would both be contained in the same module whose public API consists solely of the function `foo` and thus it is the only function exported.

```
function foo ()
{
    $p = bar "here"
    "result is '$p'"
}
function bar ([string] $s)
{
    $s + $s
}
Export-ModuleMember foo
```

Is there any way to view the nested, non-exported functions (like function `bar`) within another function in a fashion comparable to (A) or (B) above? (That is, *without* opening the .psm1 file in an editor :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it for a particular function in a module but you can do it for the whole module:

```
Import-Module C:\Test.psm1
(Get-Module Test).Definition
```

I think the fact that function foo calls function bar is not known until runtime.

**Update**

Where there's a will, there's a way :-) Here's how you can access private module members. Invoke the module with a scriptblock. Inside the scriptblock the private members are visible.

```
Import-Module C:\Test.psm1
$module = Get-Module Test
& $module { (get-item function:bar).Definition }
```

Thanks to PowerTips :-) http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2009/09/18/accessing-hidden-module-members.aspx

**Update 2**

After finding the little PowerTip snippet I was kinda curious what was really going on... The snippet uses the call operator `&` with two arguments.

1. The module object (`System.Management.Automation.PSModuleInfo`)
2. A script block

So what's really going on is the `Invoke` method of the `PSModuleInfo` type is being called. The code in the script block runs within the same session state as the rest of the module code so it has access to the private members. This code does the exact same thing as the PowerTip snippet:

```
$module = Get-Module Test
$module.Invoke( { (get-item function:bar).Definition } )
```

Check out the invoke method here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psmoduleinfo.invoke(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I understand your point but let me clarify. I am not looking to display all nested *automatically*. Rather, once I look at the top level function I say to myself "OK, this function calls function xyz. Now I want to look at function xyz." But `gc function:xyz` will fail because it is not exported.

Comment: Nice find; thank you, Andy! Note that the shorter format (my format A above) also works, i.e. `& $module { gc function:bar }` as the last line of your recipe.

Answer (score 0):

No. The method you're using is getting the definition of the function via the function provider in the local scope.  It will only see functions that have been defined in the local scope or that are visible in parent scopes.

When you call a function, it runs in it's own scope.  Any functions the function creates will be created in that child scope, and only exist during the time that function is running.  When the function is done, the scope it was running it gets disposed of, and all the functions it created go with it.